# Generic types for function which creates functions that wrap other functions

Tags: typescript

How would I write generic types for the function `createWrapper` such that the return types at the end of the example are as specified?

```
function createWrapper(wrapper) {
  return fn => wrapper(fn);
}

const wrap = createWrapper(fn => {
  if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
    return 4 as const;
  }
  const result = fn();
  return result === 0 ? null : result;
});

const nullOrOneOrFour = wrap(() => {
  return Math.random() < 0.5 ? (0 as const) : (1 as const);
});

const twoOrThreeOrFour = wrap(() => {
  return Math.random() < 0.5 ? (2 as const) : (3 as const);
});

// ReturnType<typeof nullOrOneOrFour> -> null | 1 | 4
// ReturnType<typeof nullOrTwoOrThreeOrFour> -> null | 2 | 3 | 4
```

The definition of the function `createWrapper` is the only area where there should explicit type annotations. Everything else would ideally be inferred.

---

After playing around with this some more I'm thinking I may need something like higher-order types to do this properly (i.e. generic generics). This comment seems related to what I'm trying to accomplish: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213#issuecomment-523245130.

Comment: sorry whats the code for createWrapper. isnt that what you want to type

Comment: @jstuartmilne I added the code for `createWrapper`

Comment: In the comment you mention `nullOrTwoOrThreeOrFour` but in the code you have `twoOrThreeOrFour`. Is the comment supposed to say `twoOrThreeOrFour`?

Answer (score 1):

I've gone through and added types to everything until the rest could be inferred.
You can probably choose different things to add types to to get the results to be inferred correctly.

### The typed code

```js
function createWrapper<Output, FinalOutput>(wrapper: (fn: () => Output) => FinalOutput): (fn: () => Output) => FinalOutput {
    return fn => wrapper(fn);
}

const wrap: <Output>(fn: () => Output) => Output | 4 | (0 extends Output ? null : never) = createWrapper(fn => {
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
        return 4 as const;
    }
    const result = fn();
    return (result as unknown === 0 ? null : result) as any;
});

const nullOrOneOrFour = wrap(() => {
    return Math.random() < 0.5 ? (0 as const) : (1 as const);
});

const twoOrThreeOrFour = wrap(() => {
    return Math.random() < 0.5 ? (2 as const) : (3 as const);
});
```

`nullOrOneOrFour` gets inferred as `null | 1 | 4`,
and
`twoOrThreeOrFour` gets inferred as `2 | 3 | 4`,

### `createWrapper`

Takes a function that takes a single function and returns some value,
and returns a function that takes a function and returns that value.

Honestly, I'm not really quite sure what it's for, since it doesn't do anything to functions that take one argument. Maybe you have some use case for it I can't think of, but either way it's a good example for the typing system.

### `wrap`

Takes a function that outputs something, and outputs that something, `4`, or `null` if that something is `0`.

Unfortunately, I had to add an `as unknown` to `result` in this function, since apparently you can't compare arbitrary types to `0` in typescript. I don't think this makes sense, but it's [intended behaviour](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31555).

Also, I had to add `as any` to the final return since I couldn't get it to type so that `null` was only possible if `0 extends Output`. It makes the typing of this function ugly, but makes the type inference in any of its callers nice. If another answer can get rid of the `as any` but still get the correct type inference on the last two constants, their answer is probably better than mine.

Comment: I added some additional context to the question to make the ask clearer. `createWrapper` is the only function that should have explicit type annotations.

Comment: @Braden That might be a bit optimistic. The following function's return type cannot be inferred correctly:

`function replaceNullWithZero<T>(t: T) { return t === 0 ? null : t; }`

Since you have something like that in `wrap`, it's not going to type infer correctly, regardless of what you do with `createWrapper`.

Answer (score -2):

Here's the simple example of return type of function.

```
greet() : number {
    return n;
}
```

Comment: doesnt even come close to the complexity of the question being asked